# Create Table in a Loop inside Stored Procedure Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-partitioning

I am attempting to create a Oracle stored procedure which creates partitioned tables based off of a table containing the table names and the column to be partitioned with. A separate PL/SQL block iterates through the table and calls the procedure with the table name and the column name.

Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE exec_multiple_table_create (
    table_name  IN VARCHAR2,
    column_name IN VARCHAR2
) IS
    stmt       VARCHAR2(5000);
    tablename  VARCHAR2(50);
    columnname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    tablename := table_name;
    columnname := column_name;
--    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tablename);
--    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(columnname);
    stmt := 'create table '
            || TABLENAME
            || '_temp as (select * from '
            || COLUMNNAME
            || ' where 1=2)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt
        USING IN table_name, column_name;
    stmt := 'alter table '
            || tablename
            || '_temp modify partition by range('
            || columnname
            || ')
            (PARTITION observations_past    VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20000101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2000 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20010101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2001 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20020101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2002 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20030101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2003 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20040101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2004 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20050101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2005 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20060101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20070101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20080101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2008 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20090101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2009 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20100101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_CY_2010 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(''20110101'',''YYYYMMDD'')),
                 PARTITION observations_FUTURE  VALUES LESS THAN ( MAXVALUE ) )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt
        USING IN table_name, column_name;
    RETURN;    
END exec_multiple_table_create;
```

The PL/SQL block which is using the stored proc is:

```
BEGIN
    FOR partition_item IN (
        SELECT
            table_name,
            partition_column
        FROM
            partition_table
    ) LOOP
        exec_multiple_table_create(partition_item.table_name, partition_item.partition_column);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Now, when I try executing the thing, this is what I am seeing:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00905: object SCG_MYACCT_CUSTOMPC.EXEC_MULTIPLE_TABLE_CREATE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I have a feeling that I am missing something. Please let me know what it is. The table containing the reference data exists and contains data.

I have tried refreshing the table, rewriting and modifying the pl/sql block & the procedure code. Nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
There was a glitch in the stored procedure where I needed to refer to the `tablename` rather than the `columnname` in the code above. However, I am getting a different error right now.

```
Error report -
ORA-06546: DDL statement is executed in an illegal context
ORA-06512: at "SCG_MYACCT_CUSTOMPC.EXEC_MULTIPLE_TABLE_CREATE", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 9
ORA-06512: at line 9
06546. 00000 -  "DDL statement is executed in an illegal context"
*Cause:    DDL statement is executed dynamically in illegal PL/SQL context.
           - Dynamic OPEN cursor for a DDL in PL/SQL
           - Bind variable's used in USING clause to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a DDL
           - Define variable's used in INTO clause to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a DDL
*Action:   Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE without USING and INTO clauses to execute
           the DDL statement.
```

Please help me out with this as well.

**UPDATE 2:**
I removed the `USING` part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. That seemed to take care of the error I posted. Getting a different error with versions now:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
    FOR partition_item IN (
        SELECT
            table_name,
            partition_column
        FROM
            partition_table
    ) LOOP
        exec_multiple_table_create(partition_item.table_name, partition_item.partition_column);
    END LOOP;
END;
Error report -
ORA-00406: COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be 12.2.0.0.0 or greater
ORA-00722: Feature "Conversion into partitioned table"
ORA-06512: at "SCG_MYACCT_CUSTOMPC.EXEC_MULTIPLE_TABLE_CREATE", line 37
ORA-06512: at line 9
ORA-06512: at line 9
00406. 00000 -  "COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be %s or greater"
*Cause:    The COMPATIBLE initialization parameter is not high
           enough to allow the operation. Allowing the command would make
           the database incompatible with the release specified by the
           current COMPATIBLE parameter.
*Action:   Shutdown and startup with a higher compatibility setting.
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the `stmt` value using `dbms_output` to check it is what you expect? It seems to be like: `create table tablename_temp as select * from columnname where 1=2`.  Did you mean to use `columnname` there in the `from` clause?

Comment: Actually, you might be right. Thank you so much for the help. Now getting a different error though. Will update the question.

Comment: To begin with, remove the USING .... from your execute immediate... as there are no bind variables in your SQL. Second, when you create the procedure, it seems to be raising an error, so get that error (show err in sqlplus, ...) and add it to your post

Comment: @gsalem I removed the `USING` part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. That seemed to take care of the error I posted. Getting a different error with versions now. Thanks a lot for pointing towards the right path. Will update the question with the latest error string.

Comment: `alter table ... modify partition` is a 12.2 feature - are you on 12.2 or higher? If so, you need to speak with your DBA to up the compatible parameter. Or you can put the partitioning clauses directly in the create table. `create table ... partition by ... as select`

Comment: Creating tables should be a one-time operation.  I can't help but wonder how much time has been and will be spent on this project, vs.  simply coding up a simple sql script, in a decent text editor to facilitate copying and pasting repeating code.

Comment: "exec_multiple_table_create" seems a slightly inappropriate name for a procedure that creates one table. Are all your procedures named 'exec_'?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon, you are right; we are still on 12.2. The DBAs are unwilling to perform this operation from their side hence having to take this route.